# Linq using sum() in list within a list

Tags: c#, linq

The relationship between them is one order to many journals. Now I want to get the sum of all pending orders (or records that are flagged as `false` under `IsDelivered` in `Order` entity).

So far, I have this query but can't seem to get working when I add `.Sum()`

`Orders
.Where(o => o.IsDelivered == false)
.Select(o => new {
    pendingOrders = o.Journals.Sum(j => j.TotalAmount)
})`

So far this results to:

In a nutshell, how can I get the sum of them? If query needs to be altered or should be a new one. It is welcome. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in several ways:

- You could add `Sum(n => n.pendingOrders)` to the end of your query to add up the values, or
- You could use `SelectMany` before `Select`, and use `Sum` instead of `Select`.

Either of the two approaches is going to work.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, it is easiest to use `SelectMany` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.100).ASPx)) to flatten your collections, then use `Sum`:

```
Orders.Where(o => !o.IsDelivered).SelectMany(o => o.Journals).Sum(j => j.TotalAmount);
```